# Message Queue Overflow avoidance

Tags: debugging, operating-system, pthreads, embedded, ipc

I am using a message queue Template in C++ to queue my messages which happens to  queue SIP messages.My queue size is fixed and when I increase the rate and number  of messages I am able to detect an over flow in the message queue.

I would like to avoid the message queue overflow. So if some one can guide me in practical overflow avoidance techniques in message queues It would help much.

Suggestions regarding popular POSIX message queue overflow avoidance are also welcome as I would get some ideas from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to detect overflow situation, which is great. Next you just need to define the behaviour upon overflow. Usually there are two choice: block or fail.

Fail upon overflow is obvious, blocking queue would require a mutex and condition variable:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
while ( full() ) {
  cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::microseconds(milliseconds));
  // TODO: or define a max wait time and fail accordingly.
};
add(message);
return;
```

And do `cond.notify_one()` when the queue is consumed and no longer overflow.

Comment: If you detect overflow, it already occured. OP is asking how to **avoid**, which is too broad.

Comment: I suppose by detecting overflow the OP mean checking if the queue is full, by something like checking queue counter, and nothing has really occur. And by blocking or failing when the queue is full does avoid overflow.

Comment: Full and overflow are clearly defined. Unless changed, I'll take what OP wrote. Note that "Full" condition is likely already too late, because there might be no time left to stop the next message underway.

Answer (score 2):

What you normally have for messaging queues is not Overflow - because overflow is just too late. You have something like High Watermark. (Low Watermakr is also worth mentioning, because when you are consistenly on Low Watermark it means you probably have too lengthy queue or too many handlers).

Once you hit High Watermark you signal to the user. You can also implement several strategies, depedening on the semantics of the messages. For instance, you might start skipping every second message. You might use 'overflow buffer' - extrenely lightweight handler which will simply read all messages from the queue and store them in some sort of buffer, may be as simple as file, for later processing. You might do a lot of things, but again, you do it on High Watermark, not when the queue is already full.